# kendo dropdownlist shows optionlabel in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using kendodropdown. I used optionLabel = "Actions" and it is displayed as an option in the dropdown how do I ignore it as a value in dropdown.

Is there a way where we can stop or hide optionLabel in kendo dropdownlist to be displayed as an option in the dropdown.

```
var $dropdownElement = $("<input />");

$dropdownElement.appendTo($dropdownContainer);
$dropdownElement.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: dropdown.items,
        optionLabel: 'Actions'
})
```

As of now Actions is displayed as an option in the dropdown please help me to ignore it as a value in dropdown.

Comment: (As per my knowledge) It is default functionality of drop down list we can not change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution that worked well, I am hiding the first element when I click the dropdown.

```
var $dropdownElement = $("<input />");

$dropdownElement.appendTo($dropdownContainer);
$dropdownElement.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: dropdown.items,
        optionLabel: 'Actions',
        open: function () { $($dropdownElement).getKendoDropDownList().list.find("li.k-item").first().hide(); 
                }
})
```

Comment: it is better to hide element with class 'k-list-optionlabel', not first element. It has separate class

Answer (score 3):

I am extending from @Shashi's answer and @MarkosyanArtur's comment in the same answer. The `open` event fires every time the user tries to expand the DropDown list. Why not use `dataBound` event instead? Also, an additional tit-bit, the `this` specifier links to the ddl itself, therefore;

```
var $dropdownElement = $("<input />");

$dropdownElement.appendTo($dropdownContainer);
$dropdownElement.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: dropdown.items,
        optionLabel: 'Actions',
        dataBound: function () { this.element.getKendoDropDownList().list.find(".k-list-optionlabel").hide(); }
})
```